# Set delay between different threads in the same group

Tags: jmeter

I want to simulate the following use case. Multiple users login to a server, then after all of them are logged in (and all of them have the required cookies), they do a certain action on the server at different intervals of time.

E.g.

`- User1 -> Login 
- User2 -> Login
- User3 -> Login
- User1 -> POST foo
- Wait 2 sec
- User2 -> POST bar
- Wait 2 sec
- User3 -> POST foobar
- End`

**Question**: How do I add a delay between the POST actions without having to add the same delay for the login actions?

My Jmeter config looks like this:

`-- Test Plan
  |- HTTP Cookie Manager
  |- Thread Group
   |- login (HTTP request)
   |- Synchronizing Timer (to wait for all threads to login)
   |- post (HTTP request)`

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer right to your "post" sampler.

So it's going to look like that:

```
-- Test Plan
  |- HTTP Cookie Manager
  |- Thread Group
   |- login (HTTP request)
   |- Synchronizing Timer (to wait for all threads to login)
   |- post (HTTP request)
    |- your 2 sec constant timer
```

If you need something conditional, you may use BeanShell/JSR223 timer instead.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. What happens after this change is that you just have a single X second delay between the login and the POST actions, but after that there is no delay between the POSTs of the different threads. This doesn't satisfy the flow that I posted in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You would have to add constant timer inside the post request so that everytime before post request delay of those many second will occur.

Two implement your scenario we can set jmeter elements as below :
[image]